# Laravel Multi Insertion and its relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know about Model::insert() But how about its associated relationship?

We know we can have 100 question after form submit but corresponding question have around 4 answer (For multiple choice questions)

Our question data look like this

```
$question = [
 '1' =>[
        'name'='Who is first president of America'?
        ...
    ]
    ...
 '100' =>
    'name' = 'When did Christopher Colombus discovered America'
    ....

    ...
]

$answers = [
    '1'=>
        [
            '1' => 'Wilston Churcil',
            '2' => 'George Washinton'
            ....
        ]
        ...
    ...
]

$correct_answer = [
    '1'=>['2']
    ...
]
```

Relationship

- Question has many Answers
- Question has many Correct Answers

We are trying to upload many questions at once

We can clearly see if we don't go for laravel create otherwise we will run n+1 problems and for 100 question we may probably need 100 + 400 + 100 queries which is extremely inefficient?

If Question::insert() has returned id of inserted question then it would be easy but it just return Boolean ..

Is there anyway to solve such issue without using n+1 problem.

I tried using n+1 and background job but it is really extremely slow :(

Any solution and hacks would be ok :(

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models has some options for inserting via the model object. `saveMany` looks like it does what you need

Comment: doesn't that create n+1 problem?

You need to save every individual question turn by turn grab those all and insert answers and corresponding answers ?

Comment: No the idea is to insert a question and its answers before inserting the next question. Also the N+1 problem is to do with selects not inserts.

Comment: @apokryfos yes but if we insert questions individually then it is like n + 1 problem. Yes the main thing is how to get those inserted id?

Answer (score 1):

The `hasMany(..)->saveMany([$array])` methods runs only 1 query to save all the object inside the $array. You will still need to iterate through all your answers though.

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question) {
    $answerArray = []
    foreach($answers[$key] as $answer) {
        $answerArray[] = new App\Answer($answer[1], $answer[2], $answer[3], ...)
    }
    $q = new App\Question($question['name'], ....);
    $q->save();
    $q->answers()->saveMany($answerArray);
}
```

If this is still too slow, i think your only option is to create a job to save your data in a different task ([Official docs about jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#creating-jobs)), so the web request doesn't need to wait until all the data is saved.

Comment: Hello. you are trying to insert 100 questions at first isn't that slow at first place?

Yes your answer is first.

Comment: No, 100 queries are not too many. Unless your computer usage is already behind his limit, a standard query took a fraction of a second. 100/200 queries will, at maximum, take some seconds. If you can't afford that, the only solution is to use asynchronous code with a job.

Comment: I just gave 100 as example bro :) it can be 1000. Is there any solutions to it?

Comment: As i already said 2 times, you should really use jobs to handle data asynchronously in that case. Even if you manage to compact everything in a single query, it will be so huge that will still take too much. The better approach is to split data in batch and save them with jobs.